# Can fraud activity cause an IPN script to fail?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Payments from my website continue to be logged on paypal.com, but the IPN script is not processing those transactions in my database. Members who have upgraded are complaining that they are not getting access to the paid features. The odd thing is, I have not touched the IPN script, written in PHP, for months! I'm baffled as to why it suddenly stopped working, so are the tech support boys at Paypal. I'm convinced it has something to do with the fraud that took place on my merchant account this past weekend, but Paypal denies it.  When I alerted them of fraud activity on my account, they rightfully deactivated my paypal debit card.  It was around that time that my IPN script stopped working.

Any ideas on what is happening behind the scenes here?  I can understand if I was messing with the code recently, but I wasn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the IPN history in your account show any posts being attempted to your IPN URL?  Also make sure that you still have IPN enabled in your account.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was paypal's fault once again.  Late in the afternoon the whole process started working again, without me editing the IPN script at all.